# Sails.js body contents when Content-Type is text/csv

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

Do I need to do anything special to handle `POST` requests with a text-ish `Content-Type`?

I need to handle `text/csv` but when I get to the method in my controller, it looks like Sails.js tried to parse the body as JSON:

```
postStuff: function(req, res) {
    sails.log.info("postStuff")
    sails.log.info(req.body)
    sails.log.info(req.headers['content-type']);
...etc...
```

gives me:

```
info: postStuff
info: {}
info: text/csv
```

I find the documentation on the `bodyParser` middleware a little bit obscure.

FWIW, I also tried setting the `Content-Type` as `text/plain` in the request, to no avail.

I also tried explicitly adding a text bodyParser as middleware, which didn't seem to have any effect:

**http.js**

```
module.exports.http = {
  bodyParserText: require('body-parser').text(),
  middleware: {
    order: [
      'startRequestTimer',
      'cookieParser',
      'session',
      'myRequestLogger',
      'bodyParser',
      'bodyParserText',
      'handleBodyParserError',
      'compress',
      'methodOverride',
      'poweredBy',
      '$custom',
      'router',
      'www',
      'favicon',
      '404',
      '500'
    ],
...etc...
```

Comment: Note the ordering of `bodyParserText` in the `middleware.order` list didn't make any difference, either.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, this turned out to be easy... but annoyingly hard to debug due to the lack of feedback from the framework.

In `https.js`, the element for the new middleware had to be inside the `middleware` element... which if course makes sense:

```
module.exports.http = {
  // NOT HERE
  //  bodyParserText: require('body-parser').text(),
  middleware: {
    // HERE
    bodyParserText: require('body-parser').text(),
    order: [
      'startRequestTimer',
      'cookieParser',
      'session',
      'myRequestLogger',
      'bodyParser',
      'bodyParserText',
      'handleBodyParserError',
...etc...
```

Would have been nice if sails.js (express?) gave a warning, since I'm assuming it couldn't find `bodyParserText`.